# Function cannot return a value

Tags: c, function, quicksort

I'm writing a code for a Quick Sort arrangement function in C, but in a recursive call of the function it shows the following error: ***Arrange(int,int) cannot return value.***

```
void Arrange(int left,int right){ 
    int i,j,x,w;
    i=left,j=right;
    x=(left+right)/2;
    do{
        while(struct[i].number < struct[x].number)i++;
        while(struct[j].number > struct[x].number)j--;
        if(i<=j){
            w=struct[i].number;
            struct[i].number=struct[j].number;
            struct[j].number=w;
            i++;j--;
  }}while(i<=j);
    if(left<j)
  return Arrange(left,j); //1st recursive call. It doesn't work.
    if(right>i)
  return Arrange(i,right); //2nd recursive call.It doesn't work either.
    };
```

Why is this happening?

This is just a function of the a bigger program, which i'm not posting because it seems more like a logical problem of the function. The struct it's already defined in the complete program.

Comment: return type is `void`. so how can u return a value ??

Comment: Also, `struct` is a keyword, not a valid identifier...

Comment: Mark it as answered if you have got your answer please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function is declared to return `void`.  That makes your `return` keywords superfluous.  Just delete them.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared function `Arrange()` as `void`, and obviously a `void` function cannot return a value by definition.

As stated by @CarlNorum, simply remove the return statements.

Comment: Well that wast fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

remove the `return` statement before calling Arrange, since void doesn't return anything.

```
}}while(i<=j);
    if(left<j)
  Arrange(left,j); //1st recursive call. It doesn't work.
    if(right>i)
  Arrange(i,right); //2nd recursive call.It doesn't work either.
};
```

Comment: looks like @Carl Norum beat me to it

Answer (score 1):

Syntax  : **Return_Type Function_Name Arguments**

and here you define void means returns nothing

Answer (score 1):

A function that returns `void` means it does not return a value at all. C does not allow you to use the `return` statement with an expression (even if it is a `void` one) if your function is declared as `void`.

Since this is supposed to be a quick sort, I assume you actually want to sort both the lower half and upper half. So returning was the wrong thing to do anyway (returning would have caused half the array to go unsorted). Remove the `return` keywords from your recursive calls. Let the function fall off the end of the function to signal the end of the function call.

```
if(left<j) Arrange(left,j);
if(right>i) Arrange(i,right);
```

Comment: As an extension, GCC (and G++) actually accepts `return` statements with a `void` type expression.

Comment: @Lowpower: Doesn't everyone use `-pedantic -Werror`? C++ allows returning `void` because it simplifies the writing of templates that return the result of a callable template parameter.

Comment: jxh, no, it is obvious that not everyone use `-pedantic`.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the function is **void** so there's no way a function can return any value.